# Telnet to Server Trying to Open Program Cant see it

Tags: windows, telnet

I telnetted to my server and i tried to open a simple program say notepad.exe or skype.exe.For some reason on my desktop it does not open when i use telnet to do so, but a process does initiate when i run it from telnet.

How come i cant see the program open on my desktop when i telnet to my server and run a program?

I am running the telnet server on a vm and using the client on my host computer.

I run simple command like this

```
*===============================================================
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Server.
*===============================================================
  C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone>Skype.exe
```

Comment: I think i found something for this solution over @ http://serverfault.com/questions/23695/how-to-start-a-windows-gui-app-from-telnet

Answer (score 0):

Telnet is a text-based utility. Notepad, Skype, et al require a graphics interface not available to a telnet client, therefore they won't start. It doesn't matter that the telnet client and server are on the same hardware.

You can initiate a process on a remote machine via a telnet client because it doesn't require a user interface.

Comment: So there is no way to send a telnet command to open skype? Because I saw it done on a Windows CE once.

Comment: Looking at the link you posted above, there's no _simple_ way to do this. I can conceive of a method using some software installed on the telnet server that you could force an interaction with. I'm not a Windows programmer, so I can't provide code, nor can I suggest something that might work.

Comment: I was able to to do using psexec

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/23695/how-to-start-a-windows-gui-app-from-telnet